# How to index media files in android for fast search

Tags: android, search, indexing, mp3, media

I have music application which can play music from cloud.
Users can download their favorite songs to listen without internet-connection.
Earlier file-names of downloaded songs exactly matched their ID in cloud. For example a34dsa335dkf.mp3, 34fdnn34n2n1.mp3, ...

This naming method convenient for fast search. But not convenient for people, because file names like a34dsa335dkf.mp3 don't tell them anything. For example if somebody wants to copy his downloaded song to somewhere else, he will not know what to copy.

I'm looking for some indexing mechanism, so i can name files human-readable (for example Madonna-Frozen.mp3 instead of a34dsa335dkf.mp3) and i can quickly find this files on demand.
I can't simply match file-name to ID in cloud. Because of possible duplicates.

Can someone give me advice how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not well-experienced on this so please take this as a newbie suggestion. I would suggest to use MP3 `metadata` to put your user's ID in and rename the files to a more descriptive name like the one you mentioned e.g. `Madonna-Frozen.mp3`

There are few **Java** libraries to read and write MP3 metadata which you may give them a try:

- [`jd3Lib`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jd3lib/) is an **id3/mp3** library written in Java. It provides functionality for reading **mpeg** information such as the bitrate, sample rate, channelmode, etc. It also allows the reading, writing, and removal of **id3v1** and **id3v2** tags
- [`JavaMusicTag`](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/docs.htm) This library reads song information, such as song title, artist, and album, from an MP3 file. It supports **ID3v1**, **ID3v1.1**, **Lyrics3v1**, **Lyrics3v2**, **ID3v2.2**, **ID3v2.3**, and **ID3v2.4** tags. MP3 Frame Headers can also be read. There is a **FilenameTag**, a **ID3v2.4** tag that is intelligently derived from the file name. It contains tag synchronization utilities, multiple save options, and easy tag conversion methods.
- [`JAudioTagger`](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) is the Audio Tagging library used by Jaikoz for tagging data in Audio files. It currently fully supports **Mp3**, **Mp4** (**Mp4** audio, **M4a** and **M4p** audio) **Ogg**, **Vorbis**, **Flac** and **Wma**, there is limited support for **Wav** and **Real** formats.

I'm pretty sure you will get a better approach from experts.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I think this can be a good solution. I will check this links.